# Restrict the scroll up of list view after a particular row

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll, android-viewpager

The title is little confusing let me explain my problem ,i have some data in list view and its is scrollable and there is no issue in that sort of problem.my requirement is while i scroll and for example the  list views first visible portion is 2 then it should stop the scroll up.But we can scroll down,its like restring the scroll up of list view after a particular row is the first visible item in that list view.i tried some of the code but it has a problem it disable the entire scroll i cant scroll down the  list view i use this method to disable the scroll of listview

```
    public void enableDisableView(View view, boolean enabled) {
    view.setEnabled(enabled);

    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view;

        for (int idx = 0; idx < group.getChildCount(); idx++) {
            enableDisableView(group.getChildAt(idx), true);
        }
        for (int idx = 0; idx < group.getChildCount(); idx++) {
            enableDisableView(group.getChildAt(idx), true);
        }
    }
}
```

i also used

> mListView.setSelectionFromTop(1, 0);,smooth scroll etc

but it does not works.is there any idea or solution to achieve this aim.

Thank you

Comment: I think you have to implement your logic in OnScroll().

Comment: i tryed some but it did not give me a proper solution is the any way to restrict only the scroll up of a list view?

Comment: Have you tried smth like removing that items from adapter or set these items to particular type with 0 height?

Comment: no .but how can that be done?